# What is Bourbaki's definition of subfield? or categorical definition of subfield?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Let $F$ be a field.

Let $K$ be a subset of $F$ which is closed under two binary operations $+,\cdot$

Assume $(K,+,\cdot)$ is a field.

Is $K$ called a subfield of $F$ in Bourbaki's definition?

Or, should $K$ contain the unity $1_F$? that is $(K,\cdot)$ a submonoid of $(F,\cdot)$?

Comment: $+_K = +_F$?...

Comment: See Nicolas Bourbaki, *Algebra I : Chapters 1-3* (1998), page 114 : "Let $K$ be a field. Every *subring* $L$ of $K$ which is a field is called a *subfield* of $K$. Page 103 : "**Definition 3**. Let $A$ be a ring. A subring of $A$ is any subset $B$ of $A$ which is a subgroup of $A$ under addition, which is stable under multiplication and which contains the unit of $A$."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is it true that every subfield of a field is a subring of the field?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Please consider making a solution... Thanks!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes I get it. What I just asked was that "Is a subrng $R$ of a field $F$ such that $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a field, a subring of $F$?"

Comment: dear @MauroALLEGRANZA You have provided a complete solution in a comment. I am suggesting you transfer it to an answer. Otherwise, this question will sit on the unanswered list indefinitely while nobody else bothers to answer it. Eventually, someone will just paste your answer below. It's really rather better if you put your work into a solution directly :) Hope this helps: regards

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I assumed $R$ to be an rng not ring..

Comment: "Is a subrng R of a field F such that (R,+,⋅) is a field, a subring of F?" Are you thinking to the possibility that $R$ is a field with $1_R$ such that $1_R \ne 1_F$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Nicolas Bourbaki, [Algebra I : Chapters 1-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540193731) (1998), Page 103 :

> **Definition 3**. Let $A$ be a ring. A *subring* of $A$ is any subset $B$ of $A$ which is a subgroup of $A$ under addition, which is stable under multiplication and which contains the unit of $A$.
>
> The above conditions may be written as follows:
>
> $$0 \in B, B+B \subset B, −B \subset B, B \circ B \subset B, 1 \in B.$$
>
> If $B$ is a subring of $A$, it is given the addition and multiplication induced by those on $A$, which make it into a ring.
>
> *Examples*. (1) Every subgroup of the additive group $\mathbb Z$ which contains $1$ is equal to $\mathbb Z$. Thus $\mathbb Z$ is the only subring of $\mathbb Z$.

See page 114 :

> > Let $K$ be a field. Every subring $L$ of $K$ which is a field is called a *subfield* of $K$.

---

*Note*

See the **History section** of [Ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#History) :

> Most or all books on algebra [e.g. B.L.Van der Waerden, (1930) *Moderne Algebra. Teil I*] up to around 1960 followed Noether's convention of not requiring a $1$. Starting in the 1960s, it became increasingly common to see books including the existence of $1$ in the definition of ring, especially in advanced books by notable authors such as Artin, Atiyah and MacDonald, Bourbaki [N.Bourbaki, (1998), *Algebra I : Chapters 1-3*], Eisenbud, and Lang. But even today, there remain many books that do not require a $1$.

Faced with this terminological ambiguity, some authors [...] have tried to adopt more precise terms [e.g. Joseph Rotman, *Galois Theory* (2nd ed.)] :

- rings with multiplicative identity: unital ring, unitary ring, ring with unity, ring with identity, or ring with $1$
- rings not requiring multiplicative identity: *rng* or *pseudo-ring*.